# .NET Database project and encrypted procedures

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, encryption

Is there any way how use **database project** and have **encrypted stored procedures**?

I need to have encrypted stored procedures like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
    SELECT 1
```

but when I do Schema compare against DB with encrypted stored procedure, it displays me:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
BEGIN
--The script body was encrypted and cannot be reproduced here.
    RETURN
END
GO
```

Comment: Why do you want to use encryption for your procedures? It is pretty simple to remove the encryption and it makes normal work a LOT more difficult.

Comment: It's company requirement and they argument that it's because of security

Comment: LOL. Anyone with access can break that level of encryption in a few minutes. And how do they expect people to work on their procedures if they are all encrypted? Such a silly requirement. Not sure how you get around it to be honest. They seem to contradicting themselves here. You can either encrypt the proc code or not but you can't sometime encrypt it and other times not. I doubt you will be able to use a database project with this requirement in place. You should demonstrate how easy it is to break that "security". And really how ground breaking can proc code be anyway?

Comment: Are you sure the requirement isn't TDE (encryption at rest). That would make more sense than what you are asking for.

Comment: It is'nt TDE it's just procedure encryption.

Comment: There is a web app that use DB account with role that can access just to procedures (can't directly access to tables etc.) and when someone attack DB with this account they can get information from procedures about part of DB structure. That is the reason for procedure encryption.